# JButton directly painted into panel does not show background with WindowsLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing

So, I'm developing a drag-and-drop style visual designer in Java using Swing.

Since the components that you see on the designer aren't actual components, only a visual representation (e.g. buttons can't be clicked, text fields can't accept text, etc) I'm painting them directly on my panel, overriding the methods `getX()`, `getY()`, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

It works perfectly fine on any LookAndFeel except for WindowsLookAndFeel. There, for some reason, the backgrounds of JButtons are not being painted. I have to use Windows LookAndFeel for the designer because that's how our software is deployed, and if I use a different LookAndFeel the designer layout will not be the same as our software.

I've lost a few hours trying to solve this problem, and I suspect that it's happening because by not adding the JButton on a container, it's native peer has not been instantiated. I've tried to create the peer manually, but without success.

I have noticed this problem on Windows 7 (With Aero) and Windows 8. If I use the classic theme on Windows 7 it works, so I assume it also works on Windows XP (But I haven't tested this). I'm using Java 1.7.0_25-b17 to test this.

Here's a sample I've made to show the problem:

```
package test;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestSwing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) { }

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(300, 150);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.yellow));
        p1.add(new JButton("Test"));
        f.add(p1);

        final MyButton b = new MyButton();
        b.addNotify();

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel() {
            @Override   
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                b.paint(g);
            }
        };
        p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));

        f.add(p2);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyButton extends JButton {
        public MyButton() {
            super("Test");
        }

        @Override
        public int getWidth() {
            return 70;
        }
        @Override
        public int getHeight() {
            return 25;
        }

    }
}
```

---

Here's the sample using WindowsLookAndFeel:
[image]

And here with MetalLookAndFeel:
[image]

Comment: Oh, good idea.
Here's the sample using WindowsLookAndFeel: http://i.imgur.com/KrJgeKb.png
And here with MetalLookAndFeel: http://i.imgur.com/XU2HK9q.png

Comment: Done. Note that when I tried your code with Windows L&F, it worked just fine, using Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you. That's interesting, I have tested it at my workplace on a Windows 7, I'll try again tomorrow. Maybe it has something to do with the Java version? Wich one are you using?

Comment: Now I'm using Eclipse that has Java 7, but for some reason (nothing to do with your program), I can only run at a Java 6 compliance.

Comment: Edit: I've just run it from the command line using java version 1.7.0_03. Again, no problem.

Comment: Ok, I ran it by command line just to be sure it wasn't NetBeans that was messing it up, but the problem continued. I'll try to get java 1.7.0_03 to see if it is a version issue, and I also will try again on a Windows 7 (That test will have to wait though, because I don't have any Windows 7 at my disposal)

Comment: I use `java version "1.7.0_10` on Windows 7. I have the same problem that you have. So it does look like a version problem.

Comment: *"I'm developing a drag-and-drop style visual designer in Java using Swing."*  Have you considered using your powers ..for ***good***?  The world does not need yet another (damnable) D-n-D GUI designer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm developing it from scratch because we have over 8 milion lines of legacy code in Cobol, with over 5000 windows created with our own framework, and there's no visual editor for that, so we have to make our own. Besides that, I agree with you, if we were making a software from scratch, we would definetly use an existing framework/editor.

Comment: right anybody that codeing in Cobol or RPG can creating own DND in Java from scratch, sure no issue own DND is easier:-), you have to override all methods in paint for WindowsButtonUI (special UI for WindowsLookAndFeel, doesn't works in all cases for WindowsClassicLookAndFeel == lazy to test), then paintChildren will works without any kicks from paint (should be used paintComponent or better by override paintChildren in JPanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it, thanks to your sugestion @camickr.

All I had to do was call `setSize(int width, int height)` before painting it. Looking at the Component source code, I've found this on the `resize` method (Called by `setSize`):

```
setBoundsOp(ComponentPeer.SET_SIZE);
```

I assume that this command tells the native component that it's size has changed, and without calling it the background is actually being painted, but with size 0x0.

So now, instead of creating a class MyButton and overriding the `getWidth()`and `getHeight()` methods, all I have to do is the following:

```
final JButton b = new JButton("Test");
b.setSize(70, 25);
```

And still paint it on my JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

As a potential solution. You could use a class like [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) to create an image of the button. Then just display the image an an Icon on a JLabel an you will have a real component to work with that you can drag around.

Comment: I have found out the problem, thanks to this ScreenImage class. All I had to do was to call setSize() before painting the button. I would post that as an answer, with more details, but again, not enough reputation ):